# From Excel (or any file) to Array List C#

Tags: c#, file, arraylist

I want to put some numbers from Excel to array. 
Let's say I have an Excel file  with some numbers like this:

23
34
1
3
100
56
45
43
56
4
87
6
89
9

this is just one column in excel (or any file) 
And i want to put those numers in arraylist as integer numbers, i dont need the result as one number but all those numbers to be in int value.

Any help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the above is a string (and the source does not matter), you can do the following:

```
string s = "23 34 1 3 100 56 45 43 56 4 87 6 89 9";
string[] numbers = s.Split(' ');

ArrayList numberList = new ArrayList();
int i;

foreach (String num in numbers)
{
    if (Int32.TryParse(num, out i))
        numberList.Add(i);
    else
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not a number!", num);
}

listBox1.DataSource = numberList;
```

I suggest using `List<int>` instead of `ArrayList` for type safety.

The following code reads all values from an Excel sheet into a data set using a DB connection. You can then pick the value needed.:

```
String sConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" + "Data Source=" + filename + ";" + "Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1ReadOnly=False\"";

OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection(sConnectionString);

objConn.Open();
OleDbCommand objCmdSelect = new OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM [" + sheetname + "$]", objConn);

OleDbDataAdapter objAdapter1 = new OleDbDataAdapter();
objAdapter1.SelectCommand = objCmdSelect;

DataSet dsExcelContent = new DataSet();
objAdapter1.Fill(dsExcelContent);

objConn.Close();
```

**EDIT**
You did not specify the exact source for the string, so if this question is about how to read a file or how to import data from an Excel spreadsheet, you should probably rephrase your question a little.

**EDIT 2**
Replaced `List<int>` by `ArrayList` on OP's wish (against better design).

**EDIT 3**
Added a new line to show the OP how to use the `ArrayList` as a data source for a `ListBox`...

**EDIT 4**
Added code to read Excel sheet using OleDB.

Comment: i can not change my program now, it has more than 100 lines and i did it with ArrayList,  Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Yes. Replace List<int> with ArrayList.

Comment: the problem is that i have a excel file with more than 1000 numbers in one column, and i want those numbers to be stored in array list. 
If you can write me some lines how to do all this it will be good?

Comment: That's what the above code does, only that I've initialized the string s with fixed content. In your case, s would contain the cell's content.

Comment: @AXheladini You should really think about changing ArrayList to List<T>. This can (usually) be done easily with only a few hundred or thousand lines of code and you will gain much code quality.

Comment: I try to put the value of the ArrayList in ListBox, all i get is just the first number (23).
  string s = "23 34 1 3 100 56 45 43 56 4 87 6 89 9";
            string[] numbers = s.Split(' ');

            ArrayList numberList = new ArrayList();

            int i;

            foreach (String num in numbers)
            {
                if (Int32.TryParse(num, out i))
                {
                    numberList.Add(i);
                    this.listBox1.DataSource = numberList;
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("'{0}' is not a number!", num);

Comment: Of course. You must set the data source after the loop. Otherwise the ListBox will not get notified about the new elements.

Comment: Thanks made, its good now, 
One more solution and is done, 
How to read the column from Excel in the best way, do you have any code for that ? 
i want this string s = "23 34 1 3 100 56 45 43 56 4 87 6 89 9";
to be taken from excel or some file. 
This one and all will be done?

Comment: Well, I can hardly answer "from excel or some file", because accessing an Excel file is different from accessing a CSV or XML file. You have to decide what you want.

Comment: Edited my reply and added code for reading Excel file. Use Google to find out how to address a specific column when selecting the values. This should also be possible.

Comment: I have problems now to assign the result of the dataset to string s ?

Comment: Any solution  how to join the first part with the second part ?

Comment: string s = dsExcelContent.Tables[<number of table>].Rows[y][x].ToString(); I guess you'll have to figure out the indices for yourself.

Comment: I dont know why i can not fix this, i get only the firs number from that column ? 
By the way thanks for the help

Comment: Use the debugger to inspect the dataset. Maybe the numbers are not in one column as you said. Unfortunately, there's nothing more I can do for you here - the rest you'll have to figure out yourself ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is quite easy be splitting the string and parsing each item into a list.

```
String input = "23 34 1 3 100 56 45 43 56 4 87 6 89 9";

List<Int32> result = input
    .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(i => Int32.Parse(i))
    .ToList();
```

Note that this code has no error handling. If an item is not a valid integer, an exception will be thrown. You can handle this case by using `Int32.TryParse()`. You best do this without LINQ, but you can use the following inefficent LINQ code, too.

```
Int32 dummy;
List<Int32> result = input
    .Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Where(i => Int32.TryParse(i, out dummy))
    .Select(i => Int32.Parse(i))
    .ToList();
```

Without LINQ.

```
String input = "23 34 1 3 100 56 h45 43 56 4 87 6 89 9";

Int32 dummy;
List<Int32> result = new List<Int32>();

foreach (String item in input.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
{
    Int32 number;
    if (Int32.TryParse(item, out number))
    {
        result.Add(number);
    }
    else
    {
        // Handle invalid items.
    }
}
```

Comment: i can not use LINQ since i am with VS 2005

Comment: Then use the 3rd code snippet that Daniel provided. It doesn't use linq, and will work in .NET 2.0. List<T> is part of generics.

Answer (score 0):

You could also export into a file format, ie xml or csv, and then parse this from your c# program.